# How to show my array length in google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I customized hreflang parser for my convenience. I wanted to add a counter that will show the total quantity of the languages for each website. I'm not proficient and in this and can't give you more details. Please see below for code...

```
  function extractHreflang(url) {
  var regex = /<link.*?>/g;
  var hreflangReg = /hreflang="(.*?)"/gi;
  var hrefReg = /href="(.*?)"/gi;
  
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { 'muteHttpExceptions': true, 'followRedirects': true }).getContentText();
  var result = data.match(regex);
  var results = [];
  var count = [];
  



  if(result) {  
    var n = 0;

      if(result[n].match(hreflangReg) < result.length) {
        var hreflang = getMatches(result, hreflangReg, 1).toString();
        results.push(hreflang);

      }

    if(results.length > 0) {
      return results;  
    } else {
      return 'No hreflang tags found';
    }

  } else {
    return 'Couldn\'t read URL';
  }    
}



    // FUNCTION: Get data from RegEx capture groups
    function getMatches(string, regex, index) {
      index || (index = 1); // default to the first capturing group
      var matches = [];
      var match;
      while ((match = regex.exec(string))) {
        matches.push(match[index]);
      }
      return matches;
    }
```

How would I fix this so that will be reflected in column C?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwxbo.png)

Thanks for your time! Any help on this would be great!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the length of the array of `getMatches(result, hreflangReg, 1)` to the column "C".

In this case, how about modifying your script as follows?

#### From:

```
var hreflang = getMatches(result, hreflangReg, 1).toString();
results.push(hreflang);
```

#### To:

```
var hreflang = getMatches(result, hreflangReg, 1);
results.push([hreflang.toString(), hreflang.length]);
```